# Maven archetype for Liferay Spring MVC portlet

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, liferay, archetypes

Is there any maven archetype available for liferay 6.1.0 spring mvc portlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can find a custom archetype...is it good for your needs?

https://github.com/nherbaut/liferay-maven-support/commit/46d17a16a161d820c228b11650ee3abf573d5fb7